# format not printing all double digits even when precision exceeds available digits

Tags: java, double, precision, number-formatting, bigdecimal

I can't wrap my head around this.

It seems like the JDK's number formatting routines are failing to print double digits even when given a sufficient precision field.

In particular, I don't understand why the second output line of the below program is:

> `b.doubleValue()  => 34981.29000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I believe the value printed should be `34981.29000000000087311491370201110839843750000000000000`.

Can you help me understand why this is happening:

#### PrecisionLoser.java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class PrecisionLoser {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("34981.29");
        System.out.printf("b                => %.50f%n", b);
        System.out.printf("b.doubleValue()  => %.50f%n", b.doubleValue());
        System.out.printf("b.floatValue()   => %.50f%n", b.floatValue());
        System.out.printf("Double.MIN_VALUE =>     %.50f%n", Double.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println("-");
        final double d = 34981.2900000000008731149137020111083984375;
        System.out.printf("d                               => %.50f%n", d);
        System.out.printf("new BigDecimal(d)               => %.50f%n", new BigDecimal(d));
        System.out.printf("new BigDecimal(b.doubleValue()) => %.50f%n", new BigDecimal(b.doubleValue()));
        System.out.printf("d == b.doubleValue()            => %b%n", d == b.doubleValue());
        final double e = 34981.29;
        System.out.printf("d == e                          => %b%n", d == e);
        System.out.println("-");
        System.out.printf("Double.doubleToLongBits(b.doubleValue()) => 0x%16x%n", Double.doubleToLongBits(b.doubleValue()));
        System.out.printf("Double.doubleToLongBits(d)               => 0x%16x%n", Double.doubleToLongBits(d));
        System.out.printf("Double.doubleToLongBits(e)               => 0x%16x%n", Double.doubleToLongBits(e));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
$ javac PrecisionLoser.java
$ java PrecisionLoser
b                => 34981.29000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
b.doubleValue()  => 34981.29000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
b.floatValue()   => 34981.28906250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Double.MIN_VALUE =>     0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-
d                               => 34981.29000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
new BigDecimal(d)               => 34981.29000000000087311491370201110839843750000000000000
new BigDecimal(b.doubleValue()) => 34981.29000000000087311491370201110839843750000000000000
d == b.doubleValue()            => true
d == e                          => true
-
Double.doubleToLongBits(b.doubleValue()) => 0x40e114a947ae147b
Double.doubleToLongBits(d)               => 0x40e114a947ae147b
Double.doubleToLongBits(e)               => 0x40e114a947ae147b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the conversion process with a debugger, I think what happens is that the double is first converted to a string, ignoring the precision. Then, the string is tweaked to match the specified precision (padded with 0 at end, or truncated with rounding - see applyPrecision of sun.misc.FormattedFloatingDecimal).

And, the original conversion seems to use the (smallest?) number of decimal digits that will produce the original double value, if re-parsed.

Comment: thank you for figuring that out. Do you have any idea how to get the true digits printed?

Comment: convert to BigDecimal? :)

Comment: More seriously, though, it's not clear to me why would you want to do that? In context of a double, 34981.29 and 34981.2900000000008731149137020111083984375 are decimal representations of exactly the same number..

Comment: "The minimal number of decimal digits that will produce the original value" is called roundtrip formatting. Some languages do this, including Java.